# wget to exclude certain naming structures

Tags: wget

My company has a local production server I want to download files from that have a certain naming convention.  However, I would like to exclude certain elements based on a portion of the name. Example:

- folder client_1234
- file 1234.jpg
- file 1234.ai
- file 1234.xml
- folder client_1234569

When wget is ran I want it to bypass all folders and files with "1234".  I have researched and ran across ‘--exclude list’ but that appears to be only for directories and ‘reject = rejlist’ which appears to be for file extensions.  Am I missing something in the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Top)

EDIT:
[this](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` has options `-A <accept_list>` and `-R <reject_list>`, which from the manual page, appear to allow either suffixes or patterns. These are separate from the `-I <include_dirs>` and `-X <exclude_dirs>` options, which, as you note, only deal with directories. Given the example you list, something along the lines of `-A "folder client_1234*" -A "file 1234.*"` might be what you need, although I'm not entirely sure that's exactly the naming convention you're after...